# Can someone clearly explain the feature maps, representer theorem and kernels?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra

I know that we need feature maps for representing non linear function as a linear function. And linear function can be represented as a vector and vectors can be easily manipulated by computer like a normal array. But the one thing that I don't understand what is representer theorem and what are kernels? I have a very vague understanding of them. I know that we can somehow go from d dimension to p ~ infinite dimension and calculate final result of almost infinitely large number without storing it. But still I am confused what are the kernel and representer theorem and what is the difference between kernel and representer theorem.

Answer (score 0):

since we are releasing a kernel library, I tried to do a simple introduction to kernels methods [in this Tutorial](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3766451). I hope that it will help you to understand kernel methods from a user point of view. If you want to dig in further, you might be interested to have a look to the bibliography: it links mostly to paper of mine, don't pay attention to it. However, you will find two very solid references of books of G. Fasshauer and Berlinet - Thomas-Agnan.

EDIT : sorry, the references are not in the tutorial, but in the advanced tutorial, see [enter link description here](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3769804). I copied them here. They both require a solid background on functional analysis.

A. Berlinet and C. Thomas-Agnan, Reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces in probability and statistics, Springer US, Kluwer Academic Publishers, 2004.

Gregory E. Fasshauer, Positive Definite Kernels: Past, Present and Future, available at http://www.math.iit.edu/ fass/PDKernels.pdf.